# SCCM client with dual windows boot on the same computer

Tags: sccm, configurationmanager, system-center

On a hundred PCs, I deployed via SSCM a dual boot with two Windows:

Part 1:

- Computer name "PC-Part1"
- Windows 11
- Domain1.local
- 10.0.0.0/8
- SCCM Server site name "SCCM-1"

Part 2:

- Computer name "PC-Part2"
- Windows 11
- Domain2.local
- 172.20.0.0/16
- SCCM Server site name "SCCM-2"

The SCCM client is installed on each of the two systems.

Domain1.local & Domain2.local are linked via a trust relationships

SCCM-2 is a secondary site of SCCM-1 and the two domains are recognized on this SCCM infrastructure

The problem I have is that SCCM considers these two computers as one and the same computer, while I would like each partition to be considered as a single PC to do differentiated deployments.

Do you have an idea how to do it?

Thanks

Nothing... I search on the web but no solution founded

Answer (score 0):

So generally speaking this is probably completely unsupported. From SCCMs point of view those can not be considered different because they are not.

If your problem is that you want to be able to assign different software to those machines I would recommend modifying your setups with an additional step to check against something for those computers and just ignore the installation if the check says fails.

However in theory with extreme wonky workarounds it could be possible to fool SCCM regarding this stuff.

The general method for identification is the SMBIOS GUID. This can generally not be changed but some vendors have tools for that. Even if it would be possible to change the ID from within Windows however it would still be a horrible idea to do this all the time because everytime it fails for whatever reason you get the wrong software again.

So the best thing that could work (still very wonky) would be to use a feature that blocks a certain GUID for identification. It is used for duplicates normally.
In your sites Hierarchy Settings you can find a "Client Approval and Conflicting Records" tab with a  "Duplicate hardware identifiers" section. There you could block the ID from being used for those devices on both sites. (See [this guide](https://www.prajwaldesai.com/manage-sccm-duplicate-hardware-identifiers/) for more details and screenshots)
Now it would fall back to MAC Address for identification. The best idea imho would be to use two network cards in those devices and only install one per OS completely blocking the other, but it would also be possible to spoof the MAC in one of the Drivers.

While I think this would work it also means a lot of headaches. First the spoofed MAC has to be chosen by you it must be safe from being ever matched by a real one. Then the OSD via PXE e.g. would not work at all this way. You would need lot's of workarounds possibly manually deleting the client after OSD and spoofing.
Also you could never be really sure when things go wrong if it was not a side effect of all those shenanigans.

So to summarize, maybe possible, hardly ever worth it. I don't know the reasons for your setup but from an SCCM point of view something else (maybe a VM on the client?, maybe at least completely split and unconnected sites?) would be far better supported.